# How can I upgrade window terminal installed to chocolatey?

Tags: chocolatey

I wanted to automatically update all locally installed Chocolatey packages

so, i have opened terminal as administrator and put `choco upgrade all -y`

but i saw 'window terminal upgrade error' because terminal was opened

How can I upgrade using Chocoatey?

Comment: Try running the command on native cmd/powershell console instead.

Comment: Are you saying it's not possible using Windows Terminal?

Comment: I guess not. Although you can invoke a separate powershell/cmd instance using the Windows Terminal.

Comment: Something like this should work if only one tab is open: ```Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList '-noExit','-c','cup all'; exit```

Comment: If you are facing any problem with Chocolatey itself, please report it to their bugtracker

Comment: @brc-dd You should add your comment as a proper answer because the issue is more relevant with Windows 11 where all the shells and prompts seem to open within Windows Terminal by default and you can't easily open a separate command prompt to do an upgrade.